# iOS: Is it possible to fill PDF forms?

Tags: ios, objective-c, forms, ipad, pdf

I am looking for a possibility to show a pdf with input fields so a user can fill the form and save the pdf.

[image]

I already tried some sample-solutions. The best solution I´ve found yet is [this one](https://github.com/iwelabs/ILPDFKit). It does exactly what I want to achieve but unfortunately it is not working with some pdf-versions.

// EDIT: added image

Comment: It may probably not answer the question, but what speaks against using a PDF viewer which supports fields? (for simple filling, without logic, even Adobe Reader does it; if the forms contain logic, PDF Expert from Readdle is currently the leader of the pack).

Comment: For interest's sake, which are the PDF versions that product does not work with? Or is it XFA forms? To find out, you might open the form in Adobe Reader/Acrobat on a computer and display the document properties.

Comment: Nothing speaks against a PDF viewer which supports fields. That would be a preferred solution but unfortunately I can not find such a PDF viewer. I need to send the filled pdf to a server so I will need to integrate such a viewer into my app.

Comment: PDFExpert by Readdle would be the first choice… It even comes along with some Acrobat JavaScript support, and may also be able to deal with simple XFA forms. If the form is fillable but otherwise dumb, even Adobe Reader for iDevices can fill fields.